# Importing Stripe into Django - NameError

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I can't seem to figure out how to import Stripe into my Django project. I'm running Python 2.7.3 and I keep receiving

```
NameError at /complete/ global name. 'stripe' is not defined.
```

Even when I just open up Terminal and type `python` then

```
>>> import stripe
```

I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stripe
```

However, if I'm in the directory:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Then the above `import stripe` command successfully imports Stripe. However, as I've stated, Django does not know how to import Stripe. Might the issue be a path reference somewhere? I thought it might be a Python version issue, but regardless of whether I type `python2.6` or `python2.7` and then `import stripe`, it still does not work unless I'm in that directory above. Do I need to include stripe in my INSTALLED_APPS or somewhere in my project's settings.py file?

I installed Stripe as per their documentation:

```
 sudo pip install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe
```

Which responds with:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: stripe in ./stripe-1.7.2-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=0.8.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stripe)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=0.0.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=0.8.8->stripe)
Cleaning up...
```

At this point, I'm not quite sure what to do. Below is the Django traceback.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
 Request URL: http://localhost:8000/complete/

Django Version: 1.5.dev20120523102003
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'catalog',
 'utils',
 'cart',
 'checkout')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/Diepenbrock/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Diepenbrock/Documents/django_/ecomstore/checkout/views.py" in complete_order
  15.   stripe.api_key = "wXvAcOY6Rferd6oYNsc7Qi82aMm1KwyP"

Exception Type: NameError at /complete/
Exception Value: global name 'stripe' is not defined
```

EDIT:

```
import sys
print sys.path
import stripe
```

returns

```
['/Users/Diepenbrock/Documents/django_/ecomstore', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/Users/Diepenbrock/django-trunk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

As per an answer, I also tried `pip install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe`

This what I received:

`Requirement already up-to-date: stripe in ./stripe-1.7.2-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=0.8.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from stripe)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=0.0.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=0.8.8->stripe)
Cleaning up...`

Comment: Is it possible you are running django under a different python version that where you installed 'stripe' via pip? Can you provide the results to: `which python` ? Also, in your `views.py`, do you import `stripe` at the top? And lastly, how are you starting your dev server?

Comment: Which python returns `/opt/local/bin/python`. If I include 'import stripe' at the top of the view, I receive an error: `ImportError at /complete/` --- `No module named stripe`

Comment: That is your problem right there. You are using a macports python, but when you use `sudo` it uses your system python

Comment: You might want to consider using django-stripe-payments (https://github.com/eldarion/django-stripe-payments).

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a situation of running the django dev server under a different python interpreter than the one being used by pip. The "site-packages" location should automatically be in your path for the correct interpreter.

You should not need to add "stripe" to the INSTALLED_APPS to solve the fact that it can't be imported. You would add it for it to be included as an app and have all of its modules considered, like its models.py for instance.

Based on your comments, you are using a macports install of python as your default, but when you use the `sudo` command to install stripe, its using your system python. First off, you should try to pip install without the sudo. Or make sure `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is always in your PYTHONPATH to include both system packages and your macports.

Or, you can try using sudo with an explicit path to the python you want, so the environment doesn't guess for you:  `sudo /opt/local/bin/pip install ...`

**Virtualenv**

What you are running into makes this problem a perfect candidate for making use of [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). What you gain from using virtualenv is a completely isolated environment, using the same python interpeter all the time, and having a localized site-packages. Installing stripe would place it in that local lib.

```bsh
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv --no-site-packages myproject
cd myproject
source bin/activate
pip install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe
```

virtualenv lets you also explicitly tell it which python to use as opposed to the default:

```bsh
virtualenv --no-site-packages -p /opt/local/bin/python myproject
```

Comment: Hey jdi, I just tried installing Stripe without the `sudo`, I included the result in my question above. I'm working on the next part of your answer.

Comment: @TonyDiepenbrock: You also might have `pip` pointing to a different python interp. Basically you just have a mix of paths and pythons. The virtualenv will probably sort this out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to python path just before importing stripe :

```
import sys
print sys.path
import stripe
```

May be you have to export a PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
just before doing a python ./manage runserver

/Library/... does not sounds to be a standard path...

Comment: '/Library/...' would be a system location for OSX python

Comment: Hey Eric, I added this to my question (look above) since I couldn't include everything in this comment.