# Heroku Django Deploy Stripe Issue - No module named 'stripe'

Tags: python, django, heroku, stripe-payments

When I run my app locally, everything works, but when I try to deploy to Heroku, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
```

I've read some other answers to similar issues and it seems like maybe my virtual environment is running a different version of Python than the one on Heroku, or something along those lines?

My Python version is 3.6.5

I do have a runtime.txt file with the following in it, which I thought was setting the python version for my Heroku app:

```
python-3.6.5
```

I read this SO thread, but I didn't really understand the part about the PYTHONPATH - [Importing Stripe into Django - NameError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109114/importing-stripe-into-django-nameerror)

If anyone can help steer me in the right direction or has an idea of what I could try, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `stripe` to `requirements.txt` file in the root of your repository. You can read more about it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#the-basics).

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it.